# Java: Having trouble converting the file data to workable data in my program. Any tips?

Tags: java, arrays

Error is cannot convert arraylist to double[].
double [] data = {1, 2, 3, 4, 4} works in my functions
How would I convert the file data to useable data for my functions

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double x;
    ArrayList<Double> rawdata = new ArrayList<Double>();
    Scanner inputStream = null;
    double [] data = rawdata; //error: cannot conver arraylist<double> to double[]
    // double [] data = {1, 2, 3, 4, 4} works in my functions
    try {
        inputStream = new Scanner( new File( "RawData.txt" ) );

    }
    catch ( FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Error opening file; program aborted.");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    while(inputStream.hasNextDouble()) {
        x = inputStream.nextDouble();
        rawdata.add(x);

    }
    inputStream.close();
    // Maximum value
    double maxi = data[0];
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
        if(data[i] > maxi) {
            maxi = data[i];
        }
    }
    // Minimum Value
    double mini = data[0];
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
        if(data[i] < mini) {
            mini = data[i];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the *compile-time error* clearly states - it is not possible to convert an `ArrayList<double>` to `double[]`.

However, you can create an array with the *size* of your `Arraylist` and then place the elements into corresponding indices as shown below.

```
double[] data = new double[rawdata.size()]; // initialize array

for (int i = 0; i < rawdata.size() - 1; i++) {  // storing each element
    data[i] = rawdata.get(i);
}
```

Since the size of an array needs to be declared when it is initialized, you need to declare it with the current size of the list. Now once it's declared all you need to do is to iterate over each element in the list and store it in the array.

Comment: It works! Hate to bother you more but may you explain whats going on?

Comment: Surely. Since the size of an array needs to be declared when it is initialized, you need to declare it with the current size of the list. Now once it's declared all you need to do is to iterate over each element in the list and store it in the array.

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8 you can use stream:

```
double[] array = list.stream().mapToDouble(i -> i).toArray();
```